# Error on facebook invite

Tags: ios, xcode, fbsdk, facebook-invite

I am trying to integrate facebook invite. 
Previously it was working fine but since few days its showing like:

[image]

When i show log it showing like:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbapi20130214:///" - error: "(null)"

My Plist:

[image]

Comment: You can check your settings at developers.facebook.com and make sure if all the settings are correct. Also Facebook now provides this feature only for Games.

Comment: @MilanGupta which settings are you talking about?

Comment: All the basic settings like single sign-on, and importantly, app category. Invite friends work only if your app category is valid for the same.

Comment: @MilanGupta actually it was working fine previously. but it suddenly stop working in live application.